# Android read specific line in csv file

Tags: java, android, csv

so i have a csv file which each line is a an hex String (for exemple :

```
1/55aa55aa
2/65ba65ba
```

and so on until 64.

What i would like to know is , is there any way to point to a specific line (let's say 35) without having to read the first 34 lines ?

NB : I can already read and write the whole file.

Comment: Are the lines all the same length/is the length predictable?

Answer (score 1):

By csv you are implying each line/value is separated by a comma, so:

```
String[] hexes = yourcsv.split(",");
String line35 = hexes[34];
```

Comment: wouldn't it be hexes[34]?

Comment: Won't that be the 36th column?

Comment: @SoroushA and cricket_007, you are both certainly right. But if you wanted the first/zeroth element, it'd be hexes[0] right? I see how "line35" as a var name can be misleading.